# How do I insert a dynamic SQL oracle variable in a string?

Tags: oracle

I have a dynamic query:

```
declare

p_sql clob;

begin

​for naprav in (select naprav_name from naprav)

​ ​ ​loop​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ for pokaz in (select * from pokaz)

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​loop

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​for group_level in (select * from group_level)

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​loop

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ p_sql := '

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ insert into from_cost_lab_with_love

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ with cte as (

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ select

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.i_id_pokaz || ' as i_id_pokaz,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.pokaz_measure || ' as pokaz_measure,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.pokaz_describe || ' as "Описание показателя",

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ naprav.naprav_name || ' as "Блок данных",

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.level_name || ' as level_name,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.tb_id || ' as tb_id,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.gosb_id || ' as gosb_id,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ group_level.org_id || ' as org_id,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ' ||​ pokaz.pokaz_formula || ' as fact_amt,' --показатель

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ||​ pokaz.pokaz_formula || '  as fc_amt_1,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ row_number() over(' || group_level.partition_column || ' order by BE) as rnk

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ 0 as plan_amt,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT(''0'',KVARTAL*3 - 3)),''01''), ''yyyymmdd'') as period_begin,​ --начало квартала

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT(''0'',KVARTAL*3)),''01''), ''yyyymmdd'')) as period_end, --конец квартала

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT(''0'',MESJATS)), ''01''), ''yyyymmdd'')) as rep_date, --дата измерений

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, ''dd.mm.yy'') as load_date,

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ 0 as execution

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ from erp_trips

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ )

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ select *

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ from cte

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ where rnk=1;';

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ dbms_output.put_line(p_sql);

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​execute immediate p_sql using group_level.partition_column;

​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​end loop;

​ ​ ​ ​ ​end loop;

​ ​ ​end loop;

end;
```

It has a field pokaz. pokaz_formula, this field is taken from the pokaz table, one of the values of this field is pokaz. pokaz_formula:

```
sum(distinct RASHODY) over(:1)/count(distinct KOD_TSZ) over(:1)
```

dbms_output:

```
insert into from_cost_lab_with_love

              with cte as (

                     select

                     '99business_trips_01' as i_id_pokaz,

                     'руб.' as pokaz_measure,

                     'Командировочные расходы, руб.' as "Описание показателя",

                     'Командировки' as "Блок данных",

                     'gosb' as level_name,

                     BE/100 as tb_id,

                     GOSB as gosb_id,

                     '' as org_id,

                     sum(distinct RASHODY) over(:1) as fact_amt,sum(distinct RASHODY) over(:1) as fc_amt_1,

                           row_number() over(partition by BE, GOSB order by BE) as rnk,

                           0 as plan_amt,

                           TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT('0',KVARTAL*3 - 3)),'01'), 'yyyymmdd') as period_begin,  --начало квартала

                           LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT('0',KVARTAL*3)),'01'), 'yyyymmdd')) as period_end, --конец квартала

                           LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(FINANSOVYJ_GOD,CONCAT('0',MESJATS)), '01'), 'yyyymmdd')) as rep_date, --дата измерений

                           TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'dd.mm.yy') as load_date,

                           0 as execution

                     from erp_trips

              )

              select *

              from cte

              where rnk=1 and gosb_id <> 'ПЦП'

              order by tb_id, gosb_id
```

And when this value is substituted in the loop in the p_sql variable, the value :1 should be replaced with the value from the group_level table column, as in my code. But the compiler swears (missing right parenthesis) how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting when running the code? Also, your SQL string should not have a `;` at the end when using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Try changing the end of your SQL string from `where rnk=1;` to `where rnk=1`.

Comment: Also, can you give an example of what is being output from your `DBMS_OUTPUT`?

Comment: @EJEgyed, ';' is not a problem(i forgot remove it from there, it's not in my code).  i added dbms-output in question for you)

Comment: When binding `:1`, does what your binding actually have the `PARTITION BY` keywords? or is it just a column name?

Comment: Yeah partition by is construction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way as you can't bind a table name you can't also bind parts of an analytic function.

Example - this fails with `ORA-00903: invalid table name`

```
begin
 execute immediate 'insert into tab1(col) select col from :1' using 'TAB2';
end;
/
```

Same is valid for you trying to bind `partition by` clause

```
begin
 execute immediate 'insert into tab1(col) select max(col) over (:1)  from tab2' using 'partition by col2';
end;
/
```

This fails as you observe with `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

What you *can do*  but is for sure **what you do not want** is to bind a value in the `PARTITION BY` clause

```
begin
 execute immediate 'insert into tab1(col) select max(col) over (partition by :1)  from tab2' using 'col2';
end;
/
```

This works, but behaves in the same way as if you would ommit the partition by clause, because it corresponds to `partition by 'col2'`, i.e. partitioning on a *fixed value* results in one partition of all rows from the table.

So probaly the solution *you are looking for* is to *concatenate* the *partition by  clause* into the insert statement:

```
 execute immediate 'insert into tab1(col) select max(col) over (' || 
    group_level.partition_column || /* concatenate the partition clause in the SQL */
 ')  from tab2';
```

which will produce something like this

```
insert into tab1(col) select max(col) over (partition by col2)  from tab2
```

You should always checking for the **SQL injection** while doing so.

Comment: you want to say that I can't solve the problem with that architecture?

Comment: If you provide the table structures with some sample data and the output you are expecting, we may be able to help provide a more efficient solution to query/insert the data you are looking for.

Comment: @МарсельАбдуллин I added a solution proposal

Comment: @Marmit Bomber, But I have a different formulas(for example: sum(rashody) over(partition by gosh) and sum(rashody) over (partition by gosh) / count(nomer) over(partition by gosh). And I want to store it in one variable

Comment: I solve the problem with adding formula1 and formula2: formula1 || ‘over(‘ || partition_column || ‘)’ || ‘/‘ || formula2 || ‘over(‘ || partition_column || ‘) as fact’.  Notice that ‘)’ || ‘/‘ is different then ‘)/‘ in second variant you get an error. When I don’t need to divide I put ‘count(distinct 1)’ in formula 2

Comment: This is exact to approach I want to drive you to @МарсельАбдуллин. But don't vorget, if the formulae can be entered by wide number of users, you should check for SQL injection